# ios TableView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey I have a problem with my tableView. I fetch data from the server via NSURLSessionDataTask and when its finish I reload the table view. But I only see the data after I touch the display.

this is the code.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];


NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTast = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        tableViewArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:1 error:nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}];

[dataTast resume];
```

I set the dataSource and the delegate in the Storyboard.

Is this not possible?

Comment: All UI updates must be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `[self.tableView reloadData];` on main thread.All UI must be updated on main thread.As `tableview` is not reloading when you call the `[self.tableView reloadData];`.But when you `scroll` `tableView` it gets updated data.Put the `[self.tableView reloadData];` on main thread.

```
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTast = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        tableViewArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:1 error:nil];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];

     });
    }
}];
```

Also no need to call `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: Wow that was fast! it works awesome! I will mark this answer in 2 mins ! big thanks!